# Batch file to get count of .mea file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which will give the file name & number of lines in that file. It works properly for .txt files, but I am trying to check count of a .mea file, it shows incorrect count. (It shows very large count). below is the code,please suggest any corrections to read .mea file correctly:

```
@echo off


(
for /R %%n IN (*.*) do ( 
  for /F "tokens=1,*" %%f in ('find /V /C "-------------" "%%n"') do (

   echo %%n : %%g
  ) 
))  >output.txt
```

Comment: is .mea a binary format?

Comment: Not sure, that file is created by a software called Malvern. It opens in that software as PDF file and we can save as .txt, but i need to run the comand directly for .mea.

Comment: On further research related to that file generated by the software, got to know its format is "Evotec Flex"

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `.mea` file is a binary type file where the line terminators as understood by `Find` are not considered as terminators as understood by you. *(…without a genuine .mea file to examine we cannot help you verify that)*

I think however that you could at least further improve your code:

…single directory

```bat
@Echo Off
(   For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=- " %%A In ('Find/V /C "" *.* 2^>Nul'
    ) Do Echo=%%A %%B)>"SomewhereElse\Output.txt"
```

…recursive

```bat
@Echo Off
(For /R %%A In (*) Do For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=- " %%B In (
    'Find/V /C "" "%%A" 2^>Nul') Do Echo=%%B %%C)>"SomewhereElse\Output.txt"
```

*In both cases, unless `Output.txt` is written to `SomewhereElse`, it will show up as an entry within its own content.*